# Amazon s3 file download "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a "csv" file using S3 with Python but it returns an error regarding line `s3.download_file(bucket, origin, path)`:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
from boto3.session import Session
import boto3
import sys

ACCESS_KEY="abc"
SECRET_KEY="xxx"
path="./ListadePrecios.csv"
origin="public/excel/Nombre.csv"

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3 = session.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket("my_bucket")


def main(argv):
    #Descargar archivo
    s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    s3.download_file(bucket, origin, path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

#### Error screenshot

[image]

Comment: Paste the error as text in the question so we can see it and it will stay forever with the question.

Comment: Try by replacing `bucket` with `"my_bucket"` in `download_file`

Comment: clever how simple, thanks, now in the ʻobj.delete () `part, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing a `Bucket` object into:

```
s3.download_file(bucket, origin, path)
```

Instead, pass the bucket name:

```
s3.download_file("my_bucket", origin, path)
```

#### [Amazon s3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)

> `download_file(Bucket, Key, Filename, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)`
>
> Download an S3 object to a file.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> import boto3
> s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
> s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
> ```
>
> Similar behavior as S3Transfer's `download_file()` method, except that parameters are capitalized. Detailed examples can be found at *S3Transfer's Usage.*
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **Bucket**(*str*) -- The name of the bucket to download from.
> - **Key**(*str*) -- The name of the key to download from.
> - **Filename**(*str*) -- The path to the file to download to.
> - **ExtraArgs**(*dict*) -- Extra arguments that may be passed to the client operation.
> - **Callback**(*function*) -- A method which takes a number of bytes transferred to be periodically called during the download.
> - **Config**(*boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig*) -- The transfer configuration to be used when performing the transfer.

Comment: ready problem solved, now I am solving the delete file

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the first param of `download_file`

> download_file(Bucket, Key, Filename, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None)

Parameters are:

- Bucket (str) -- The name of the bucket to download from.
- Key (str) -- The name of the key to download from.
- Filename (str) -- The path to the file to download to.

So you should replace

```
s3.download_file(bucket, origin, path)
```

with

```
s3.download_file("my_bucket", origin, path)
```

Comment: ready problem solved, now I am solving the delete file